# Convert HTML string to MHT in memory

Tags: html, in-memory, mhtml

How can I convert an HTML string to MHT (MHTML) in memory. I do not want to use the local file system at all? I am using C#.

Comment: What programming language do you intend to achieve this with?

Comment: As stated in the question, I intend to use C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something based on [Jeff Atwood's MhtBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/MhtBuilder.aspx).